# Why my timer disappear at every milliseconds and seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Hello I have a problem with my timer and I don't understand where is the problem my problem is at every milesecunds or seconds my timer disappear and appear i don't understand why :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.BtnA.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI );
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(substractTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self reset:nil];
}

    - (IBAction)touchBtnA:(id)sender {
    if (enabledA) {
        [self.BtnA setEnabled:NO];
        [self.BtnB setEnabled:YES];
        enabledA = NO;
        enabledB = YES;
        [self.BtnA setAlpha:0.33];
        [self.BtnB setAlpha:1.0];
    } else {
        [self.BtnA setEnabled:YES];
        [self.BtnB setEnabled:NO];
        enabledA = YES;
        enabledB = NO;
        [self.BtnB setAlpha:0.33];
        [self.BtnA setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}

    - (IBAction)touchBtnB:(id)sender {
    if (enabledB) {
        [self.BtnB setEnabled:NO];
        [self.BtnA setEnabled:YES];
        enabledB = NO;
        enabledA = YES;
        [self.BtnB setAlpha:0.33];
        [self.BtnA setAlpha:1.0];

    } else {
        [self.BtnB setEnabled:YES];
        [self.BtnA setEnabled:NO];
        enabledB = YES;
        enabledA = NO;
        [self.BtnA setAlpha:0.33];
        [self.BtnB setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}

    - (void)substractTime {
    if (enabledA) {
        _remainingTimeA--;
        if (_remainingTimeA == 0)
        {
            [self pause:nil];
            [self.BtnA setEnabled:NO];
        }
        [self updateTime:A];
    }

    if (enabledB) {
        _remainingTimeB--;
        if (_remainingTimeB == 0)
        {
            [self pause:nil];
            [self.BtnB setEnabled:NO];
        }
        [self updateTime:B];
    }
}

    - (void)updateTime: (TimerType)type {
    NSInteger time = type == A ? _remainingTimeA : _remainingTimeB;
    NSInteger minutes = time / 600;
    NSInteger seconds = (time/10) % 60;
    NSInteger milliseconds = time % 10;
    if (type == A)
    {
        [self.BtnA setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%01d",minutes, seconds, milliseconds] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.BtnB setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%01d",minutes, seconds, milliseconds] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
enabledA = enabledB = NO;
```

}

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
enabledA = enabledB = NO;
[self.BtnA setEnabled:YES];
[self.BtnB setEnabled:YES];
_remainingTimeA = _remainingTimeB = 6000;
[self updateTime:A];
[self updateTime:B];
[self.BtnA setAlpha:1.0];
[self.BtnB setAlpha:1.0];
```

}

Thanks all for feature help.

Comment: Provide please error response

Comment: this is one piece of nasty code

Comment: Can you provide your methods such as `reset:` and `pause:`. Also, what actually is the problem?

Comment: If your display were disappearing every millisecond, how would you know it?

Comment: (You really should not update the display more often than about once every 0.5 seconds.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that NSTimer doesn't grant you absolute accuracy of repeating interval (1.1 in your case) of invoking selector. In other words, you should count difference between current and previous selector calls, that will be exact interval

Comment: Yes i now about this i just put 1.1 to look better when my timer start to make a update and in this is problem at every second he disappear and appear